# Minimum number of transformation required to equalize an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n positive elements (including 0). We are allowed to perform only one transformation which is to increment each element of the list except one. What are the minimum number of transformation required to equalize this list?

For example, `n = 3`, and the array being `1,2,3`. We need 3 such transformation as:

`2,3,3 --> 3,3,4 --> 4,4,4`.

For `n = 4` and the list being `1,3,2,4` the minimum number of transformation required is 6

Which is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: It looks like you are not "allowed" to incremenent n-1 elements but "required" to, am I right? Otherwise the first transformation could be 1,2,3 -> 2,3,3 -> 3,3,3?

Comment: @fge: If you decide to apply the transformation. You have to increment every element but one.

Comment: It is just that I misread the original wording: I thought you could increase _up to_ n-1 elements.

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question as the Minimum Number of Moves question in CodeChef's January Challenge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not actually need to show the transformations but find the total number of such transformations required.

Incrementing all but one element is essentially the same as decreasing one element(for the purpose of equalizing all elements).

**strategy**:
 decrease all non-minimal elements until they equal the minimal element.

for eg. If the elements are {x1, x2, x3, x4...... xn}
the number of transformations will be

```
let min = min{x1 .. xn}
for(int x : arr){
    // decrement x until x == m
}
```

Total number of transformations

```
sum(k = 1 to n)x(k)−n*min{x1,…,xn}
```

Sample run :

```
For array = {1,2,3}
sum(k=1 to n) x(k) = (1 + 2 + 3) = 6
n = 3
min = 1
num_transformations = 6 - 3*1 = 3 transformations
```

Comment: Such a good thought !
I believe one has to be good at Math to be able to solve these kind of problems within reasonable time.

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier to argue about this if you realize that your transformation is the same as subtracting 1 from one element and as a last step add n to each element where n is the number of transformation. e.g 1,2,3->1,2,2->1,1,2->1,1,1 and finally 4,4,4

And this of course means that you need (with a the array, a_i the i'th element, m the smallest element in the array) sum_i(a_i - m) transformations.

So your approach is

```
m=min(a)
for each (e in a) {
   while (e>m) {
      //transform so that e is reduced by 1
   }
}
```